# Python 3.3 tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile() leaves an unresponsive Tk window

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, filedialog

I'm trying to have the user select a file through a pop-up directory browser. Looking things up suggested that I use `filedialog.askopenfile()`, which works but leaves a small unresponsive tk window that I'd rather not have because any attempt to interact with it causes the kernel to crash and need to be restarted.

Does anyone have any solutions or alternatives? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

filedialog.askopenfile()
```